# URL as a parameter not working with Apache CXF REST /rest/http://www.google.com/

Tags: rest, cxf

I have a requirement where I need to pass URL's to a REST API as a parameter. I have tried encoding the url but I still get an HTTP 400 error code. for example

One of my sample REST API is

/rest/pull/{http://www.google.com}/net

I have tried encoding the url which results in

/rest/pull/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com/net

but this still results in an error on the REST call.
What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping dots too `/rest/pull/http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom/net`

BTW having `rest` in your APi does not make it RESTful. Start with defining resources and operations.